# Troubleshooting: Error fixing when integrating ReactJS, Solidity, and Blockchain in Visual Studio

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, solidity

Can anyone help me out? I've tried everything but this error isn't fixing. Tried to uninstall and then reinstall truflle but still showing the same error. Tested all versions but still showing the same error.
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooKWi.png)

- Error message:

  ```
  ERROR Message - "truffle : File 
  C:\Users\ayanm\AppData\Roaming\npm\truffle.ps1 cannot be loaded 
  because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more 
  information, see about_Execution_Policies at 
  https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:1 + 
  truffle init + ~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : SecurityError: (:) [], 
  PSSecurityException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess"
  ```

Comment: Please share your error message as plain text format. Also include your tried source code for further discussion

Comment: ERROR Message - "truffle : File C:\Users\ayanm\AppData\Roaming\npm\truffle.ps1 cannot be loaded because 
running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see 
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ truffle init
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess"

Comment: Did you actually try to set the policy to allow ps1 scripts?

Comment: [Search your error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=File+ps1+cannot+be+loaded+because+running+scripts+is+disabled+on+this+system.+For+more+information,+see+about_Execution_Policies+at+site:stackoverflow.com)